# I cant get this angular authentication using token to work

Tags: django, angular

There is an App x and App z. 
App x is a django application. 
App z is an Angular application.

I want a scenairo where if the link to app z is clicked from App x, the token of that user is sent with the url, then stored in session storage and the user data is gotten and stored in storage also.

```
  sessionSet(token:string)  {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8000' + '/sso_api/confirm_keys/' + JSON.stringify({'token':token}),this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe(data=>{
      sessionStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.setItem('username', data['username']);
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', data['token']);
      sessionStorage.setItem('role', data['role']);
      sessionStorage.setItem('user_id', data['id']);


      this.router.navigate(['/mail'])
      return true;

    },error => {
        alert('Cannot communicate with server, please try again')
      return false;
    })
  }
```

THis is my Auth Guard

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  _hash:string;

  constructor(private dataservice: DataService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (DataService.islogin()) {
      return true;
    }

    else {  

      const hash = route.queryParamMap.get('hash');
      if (hash) {
        if( this.dataservice.sessionSet(hash)){
          return true;
        }

      } else {
        alert("Session expired, redirecting back to app x");
        window.location.replace('http://localhost:8000')
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the django api where the token verification is done(something like that).

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def confirm_apis(request):
    token = request.data.get("token")
    print(token,"Pasted token")
    try:
        token= Token.objects.get(key=token)

        return Response({'username':token.user.username,
                         'token':token.key,
                         'id':token.user.pk,
                         'role':token.user.role
                         },status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return Response("Nothing",status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

I keep getting the cant communicate with server error i placed in the service file in the angular app(First code block above).

ALso,

statusText: "Not Found"
​
url: "http://localhost:8000/sso_api/confirm_keys/%7B%22token%22:%222801b6ac5029e793fc9bdfb0a1c1f9160b2f3b97%22%7D"

Comment: Can you post your code as text (in code formatting) rather than as an image? This makes it easier for others to help since they can copy & paste. Also what issues are you running into with your current solution? What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Looking better, thanks. Whats the actual error you're getting from the `http.post` call? Meaning what's the value of `error` there?

Comment: am not able to catch the error

Comment: `this.http.post('http://localhost:8000' + 'sso_api/confirm_keys/'....)`
there probably should be one more `/` before `sso_api/`
`this.http.post('http://localhost:8000' + '/sso_api/confirm_keys/'...)`

Comment: i actually did that, but still an error

Comment: Anyone, i have tried multiple stuffs and still cant get it to work.

@lambidu